# Android Proguard postgresql and ssl connection

Tags: android, postgresql, ssl, proguard

Having a problem with Proguard and the postgresql jdbc driver.

The problem:
04-30 19:26:36.865: W/PostgresHelper(26968): The SSLSocketFactory class provided **org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory could not be instantiated**.

This isn't a problem when in debug mode - i.e. connection is established successfully.

After "Proguarding" the project I get the above error.

I have postgresql-8.3-607.jdbc3.jar under /libs in my project.

Added -dontwarn org.postgresql.** to proguard.cfg (export won't complete without this)

This is the (altogether common) bit of code:

```
try {
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
String url = decrypt(pgurl);
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", decrypt(pguser));
props.setProperty("password", decrypt(pgpass));
props.setProperty("ssl", "true");
props.setProperty("sslfactory", "org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
Log.w(TAG, "Postgresql Class not found!");
System.exit(1);
} catch (SQLException e) {
Log.w(TAG, "Postgresql connection failure!");
Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

At this point I'm going in circles and after much googling can't reach a conclusion.
Any insights out there? ;)

TIA,
Pedro

EDIT:

In the proguard.cfg file I've added, as per Barend's kind suggestion:
`-keep public class org.postgresql.*`

As to -dontobfuscate AFAIK doesn't take any additional parameters?

this is the stack trace (when the app is "Proguarded"):

`04-30 23:11:09.355: E/System(30717): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
04-30 23:11:09.355: E/System(30717): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 23:11:09.355: E/System(30717):    at org.postgresql.d.g.close(Unknown Source)
04-30 23:11:09.355: E/System(30717):    at org.postgresql.d.g.finalize(Unknown Source)
04-30 23:11:09.355: E/System(30717):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:186)
04-30 23:11:09.355: E/System(30717):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
04-30 23:11:09.355: E/System(30717):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)`

EDIT2:
As per Eric LaFortune advice this has been solved with:

```
-keep class org.postgresql.** { *; }
```

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: are you sure you can/want to/ make a direct PG jdbc connection from android and  it is a wise thing to do it? You usually make a web service /rest/soap which is connected to the db and then you proceed with the client itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely case is that Proguard has renamed the `org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` to something like `a.a.a.a`, throwing a spanner into the reflective class loading going on. You'll want to instruct proguard to avoid obfuscating the Postgres JDBC driver.

The easy way is to whitelist it completely. The driver itself is open source, no need to be secretive about it. In your Proguard config, it'll be something like:

```
-keep org.postgresql.*
-dontobfuscate org.postgresql.*
```

Of course, its use may reveal things about your program code, so if you're really nervous, you'll want to whitelist only the minimum amount of it, so that it becomes harder to trace which parts of your code are calling JDBC. I imagine that's going to be quite a bit of trial-and-error to figure out, but it'll be much the same. You might be able to make do with `-keepnames` over `-dontobfuscate`.

Comment: The -keep option is a good start. It may be necessary to also keep classes in subpackages: "-keep class org.postgresql.**". If that's still not sufficient, it may be necessary to also keep their fields and methods: "-keep class org.postgresql.** { *; }".

Comment: Eric you're right on the "money"! :)
Thank you VERY much!
Now since you just commented how do I accept your answer as the right one?
Best regards,
Pedro.

P.S. Many thanks to Barend too :)